# gcc: why casts of literals are not optimized?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I'm coding a game for iphone in c, and after running into some performance problems I decided to use instruments to check where the bottlenecks are, and I found out that casts of literals are not being optimized.

For example:

```
if(x == (float)3) {....}
```

runs faster if I write it like this:

```
if(x == 3.0f) {....}
```

Why isn't that optimized by the compiler?
I'm using gcc in release mode.

Comment: Have you looked at the generated object code?

Comment: What is "release mode"? I don't think GCC has a `-release-mode` flag.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Probably just what Xcode calls the release configuration (as opposed to the debug configuration).

Comment: I am curious how you timed the difference in those two statements. Even if there was a difference it would be so insignificant that it would not show up and less you did it billions of times. Have you checked the resulting object code for the difference in instructions?

Comment: @BoltClock - My point was that Xcode may not be telling GCC to do any optimizations even though it's in release mode.

Comment: I tried compiling with gcc on my ubuntu a small example and the generated assembler code is identical for `(float)3` and `3.0f` both with optimization disabled or enabled.

Comment: I also tried on my system with gcc version Debian 4.4.5-8, with or without optimisation.  The code was always identical for `(float)45` and `45.`.

Comment: Sorry, you were right. I looked at the object code and is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soooorry, as the comments said, I looked at the object code and is the same.
Xcode instruments gives you line by line the amount of time spent, I see it's not 100% reliable.